# What does your return type have to implement in order for Web API to magically serialize it?

Tags: serialization, asp.net-web-api

I noticed that Web API can return a `DataTable` as JSON but balks when returning it as XML.

What is (or are) the base interface(s) that your objects should inherit from in order for Web API to automagically serialize them?

And why would it be able to serialize a given object as JSON but not XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API uses `DataContractSerializer` for XML and JSON.NET for JSON. So, the respective serialization requirements hold good with web API as well. Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx) and [this](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationGuide.htm).

`DataTable` should get serialized by DCS, since `DataTable` implements `IXmlSerializable`. If you want more control over how XML is produced, you can implement `IXmlSerializable` yourself.